# How to make my button do something in a BoxLayout?

Tags: java, swing

I made a BoxLayout GUI and i'm wondering how i'd use an actionlistener to make the button close the window. If I try to put in RegisterNew.setVisible(false); in an actionlistener, it gives me an error

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class RegisterNew extends JFrame
{
public RegisterNew(int axis){
    // creates the JFrame
    super("BoxLayout Demo");

    Container con = getContentPane();

    con.setLayout(new BoxLayout(con, axis));

    con.add(new JLabel("Enter your desired username"));
    con.add(new JTextField());
    con.add(new JLabel("Enter your password"));
    con.add(new JTextField());
    con.add(new JButton("Create Account"));

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    pack();

    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    RegisterNew newDemo = new RegisterNew(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
}
```

}

I'm also trying to link this to ANOTHER GUI so that when you press a button, this one appears, but it gives me the same error as if i put 
RegisterNew.setVisible(true); into the action listener

Comment: Please see edits to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If that's a subordinate dialog window, then use a JDialog, not a JFrame.
2. If your ActionListener is an inner class then use `RegisterNew.this.close();`
3. Else you can get the window ancestor for the JButton using `SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(button)` and call `close()` or better `dispose()` on the Window returned.
4. Note that BoxLayout and layout managers in general have nothing to do with your current problem.

e.g.,

Test class that shows the new register dialog and that extracts information from it.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TestRegistration extends JPanel {
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(30, 60);

    public TestRegistration() {
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.add(new JButton(new ShowRegisterNewAction()));
        textArea.setFocusable(false);
        textArea.setEditable(false);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JScrollPane(textArea, 
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, 
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED));
        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private class ShowRegisterNewAction extends AbstractAction {
        private RegisterNew registerNew = null;

        public ShowRegisterNewAction() {
            super("Show Register New Dialog");
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_S);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (registerNew == null) {
                JButton btn = (JButton) e.getSource();
                Window window = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(btn);
                registerNew = new RegisterNew(window, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS);
            }
            registerNew.setVisible(true);
            String userName = registerNew.getUserName();
            String password = new String(registerNew.getPassword());

            textArea.append("User Name: " + userName + "\n");
            textArea.append("Password: " + password + "\n");
            textArea.append("\n");
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TestRegistration");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new TestRegistration());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

New Register class that holds the dialog and has code for displaying it and for extracting information from it. Uses BoxLayout.

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class RegisterNew {
    private JDialog dialog = null;
    private JTextField nameField = new JTextField(10);
    private JPasswordField passField = new JPasswordField(10);

    public RegisterNew(Window window, int axis) {
        dialog = new JDialog(window, "Register New", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        Container con = dialog.getContentPane();

        con.setLayout(new BoxLayout(con, axis));

        con.add(new JLabel("Enter your desired username"));
        con.add(nameField);
        con.add(new JLabel("Enter your password"));
        con.add(passField);
        con.add(new JButton(new AcceptAction()));
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(window);

    }
    public char[] getPassword() {
        return passField.getPassword();
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return nameField.getText();
    }
    public void setVisible(boolean b) {
        dialog.setVisible(b);
    }

    private class AcceptAction extends AbstractAction {
        public AcceptAction() {
            super("Accept");
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_A);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            dialog.dispose();
        }
    }

}
```